Why these trap cards didn't activate?
I'm playing Yu-Gi-Oh! Tag Force 51 and I wonder why this situation happens:
In my LP boost deck, I'm using The Immortal of Thunder and, for avoid the second effect of "The Inmortal of Thunder", I've used these trap cards:

Barrel Behind the Door
Trap of Board Eraser

However, when the "The Inmortal of Thunder" was sent to the graveyard, the said trap cards could not be activated and then I receive 5000 LP due to "The Inmortal of Thunder"'s second effect.
I've changed "The Inmortal of Thunder" for "Granadora" and, these trap cards could be activated.
Issue: Why the said trap cards worked with "Granadora", but not with "The Inmortal of Thunder"?

N.B. In the field, there were no card or effects that prevent the
activation of these trap cards, hence, the confussion.

I've searched on yugioh wikia and in ygoresources.com, but, I've found no information about this scenario nor why this happen - I'm not sure if this is some sort of special case not documented anywhere - not even in the PSCT yugioh wikia page.
Links:

The Inmortal of Thunder - ygoresources.com
Granadora - ygoresources.com
Trap of Board Eraser - ygoresources.com
Barrel Behind the Door - ygoresources.com


1 Currently playing Yu-Gi-Oh! Tag Force 5 (and I want to try the described play on this game), but I'm looking for answers that applies to this version of the game as well for Yu-Gi-Oh! Master Duel, Yu-Gi-Oh! Duel Links and the TCG.

Yu-gi-oh has very precise language. And when a card effect like The Immortal of Thunder says 'You lose 5000 life points' this is not the same as 'you take 5000 damage'.
Barrel Behind the Door only works on damage effects, so not on 'losing life points'.
You can also find this ruling on this wiki, based on the old website from Upperdeck: https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Card_Rulings:The_Immortal_of_Thunder
